# Need a good "home" directory for web-app during Maven build

Tags: java, build-process, build-automation, maven, temporary-directory

I have a Java web application that uses JNDI to determine its "home" directory where various configuration files and logging takes place.  During a Maven build, we set the home directory location in a property that is located in settings.xml.  This property in turn gets put into the Jetty/Tomcat JNDI file during the build by Maven resource filtering.  Everything works great.

However, this set up requires that only one Maven build can happen on a machine at a time, which will be a problem soon for our Hudson CI server.  It also requires that users create this directory ahead of a build, which helps to break build portability.  Ideally I could use the "target" directory of the parent POM project as the "home" directory by defining a variable in the parent POM:

`<webapp-home>${project.basedir}/target<webapp-home>`

But this doesn't work because each Maven module redefines `webapp-home` to be something different.  I have no idea why.  If I could solve THAT problem, I'd be all set.

Otherwise, what can I use as a good temporary "home" or "working" directory, that is unique to a build and is constant across all Maven modules in the build?  And the bonus question is:  Can I have Maven create the directory for me if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

We're using a global "out" directory as webapp-home, with subfolders for every project

```
<properties>
  <root.dir>${basedir}/..</root.dir>
  <output.dir>${root.dir}/out</output.dir>
  <output.wardir>${output.dir}/wars</output.wardir>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <webappDirectory>
      ${output.wardir}/exploded/${project.artifactId}
    </webappDirectory>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Do you define the `root.dir` property in every module POM?  Or are 100% of your modules exactly one level below the parent pom?  We have a directories of nested POMs...  Still a good idea...

Comment: @HDave - These definitions are in the root pom. We then have a servlet-container pom that inherits from it, and actual servlet containers that inherit that. It works all the way down...

Comment: And each of these inheriting Maven projects are pointing to the same directory?  Hmmm....why didn't it work for me?  Will try again...

Comment: @HDave - yeah, one global out dir.